# How to use an image stored as blob in mysql in swift 5 UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, blob

This is what I have.

```
import Foundation

struct UserData: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let first_name: String
    let last_name: String
    let gender: String
    let email: String
    let joined: String
    let profile_image: [String:[String]]?
    let rating: Float
    let rating_count: Int
    
}
```

I get:

```
typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "profile_image", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "type", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

If I change struct to:

```
struct UserData: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let first_name: String
    let last_name: String
    let gender: String
    let email: String
    let joined: String
    let profile_image: [String:String]?
    let rating: Float
    let rating_count: Int
    
}
```

I get:

```
typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "profile_image", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

Not sure how to get the Image that is stored as blob in db and use it as UIImage.

This is how it comes back as response:

```
 \"profile_image\" =     {\n        data =         (\n            47,\n            57,\n            106,\n            47,\n            52,\n            65,\n            65,\n            81,\n            83,\n            107,\n            90,\n            74,\n            82,\n            103,\n            65,\n            66,\n            65,\n            81,\n            69,\n            65,\n            83,\n            65,\n            66,\n            73,\n            65,\n            65,\n            68,\n            47,\n            50,\n            119,\n            66,\n            68,\n            65,\n            65,\n            89,\n            69,\n            66,\n            81,\n            89,\n            70,\n            66,\n            65,\n            89,\n            71,\n            66,\n            81,\n            89,\n            72,\n            66,\n            119,\n            89,\n            73,\n            67,\n            104,\n            65,\n            75,\n            67,\n            103,\n            107,\n            74,\n            67,\n
```

..... it keeps going but cut off because way to long

Comment: When you don't even tell how you post image data to your remote server, how could anyone answer your question?

Comment: The image is stored in DB through web app. The server is node.js and uses base64 encoding. It looks like this.  profile_image = req.body;
let buff = base64_encode(req.file.path)
let base64data = addSlashes(buff);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct UserData: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let first_name: String
    let last_name: String
    let gender: String
    let email: String
    let joined: String
    let profile_image : Image
    let rating: Float
    let rating_count: Int
    
}

struct Image: Codable {
    var data: [UInt8]
}
```